# Animating UIButton

Tags: objective-c, ios, uibutton, core-animation

Is it possible to animate a `UIButton`?

What I want to do with my button is to animate it like a cloud where it moves back and forth in a given area only.

I've tried animating `UIImages` but I don't know if `UIButton` can be animated too.

Answer (score 3):

`UIView` instance should be animatable with `[UIView animateWithDuration:animations:]`. Since `UIButton` is a subclass of `UIView`, I don't foresee any problem...

Answer (score 3):

As already said `UIButton` instance should be animatable as its a subclass of `UIView`. The below code will move your `UIButton` back-forth i.e. left-right 20 pixels for 10 times. Basically I am chaining 2 animations together.

```
- (void)startLeftRightAnimation
{
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                  animations:^(void) 
     {
         [self.button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.logo.frame.origin.x-20,self.logo.frame.origin.y,self.logo.frame.size.width,self.logo.frame.size.height)];
     } 
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) 
     {
         if(finished)
         {
             [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                  animations:^(void) 
             {
                 [self.button setFrame:CGRectMake(self.logo.frame.origin.x+40,self.logo.frame.origin.y,self.logo.frame.size.width,self.logo.frame.size.height)];
                 [self startLeftRightAnimation];
             }
                  completion:^(BOOL finished) 
         {
         if(finished)
         {
         }
     }];
}
```